# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read the other examples where `toLowerCase` is undefined but I still don't understand. Can anyone explain why my function won't work?

```js
var changeTitle = function() {
    var loanTitle = $(this).val();
    $(this).prev().text(loanTitle);
};
```

```html
<h2>Loan One</h2>
<input type="text" onkeypress="changeTitle()" maxlength="25" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that's giving that error? toLowerCase isn't even called...??? Anyway, you need to null check variables that you call toLowerCase on.

Comment: @Barett Yes that's what pops up and I'm not too sure why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your function, the `this` object refers to the window and not the input field. Update your `onkeypress` code to the following:

```
<input type="text" name="loanName" onkeypress="changeTitle.call(this)" class="loanNameV1 qForms" maxlength="25" placeholder="Loan Name" />
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks @hoyen! It works now but why does "this" refer to the window and not the element exactly?

Comment: Because the function is part of the window object, not the input element object. So, onkeypress you are calling a function that is part of the window object. The this object will refer to the window. Using call or apply, you can change the reference of this to another object. In this case, your input field. When you get a chance, research "call" and "apply". It will help you understand it a lot better.

Comment: And to add to it, onkeypress is part of the input field's object, and so the this object will refer to the input field.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you really are trying to do, but I passed your input element as a parameter to the function you defined as `this` and I added the JQuery library to my snippet. It works with the exception that the last key stroked isn't displayed in the title. Maybe you can use this along with your toLowerCase feature and fix it up to your liking.

```js
var changeTitle = function(obj) {
    var loanTitle = $(obj).val();
    $(obj).prev().text(loanTitle);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="nameLoan1"> Loan One </h2>
<input type="text" onkeypress="changeTitle(this);" maxlength="25" placeholder="Loan Name" />
```